# Why SimpleDataFormat don't work on Mac OS X 10.6.5?

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing

I wrote a Java (Swing) application on Windows, and tried running it on Mac. But my program stopped at the `SimpleDataFormat` constructor.

Why does this happen?

I have another question too. What can I using instead of `SimpleDataFormat`?

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm | dd.MM.YYYY");
        Date dateLastUpdate = dateFormat.parse(lastUpdate.getValue());
        AccountInfo accInfo = new AccountInfo(accNumber, apiName, securityWord);
```

The first line does not execute. The date is precisely in the necessary format.

Comment: Code please...exception/stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format for parsing should be then

```
"HH:mm '|' dd.MM.yyyy"
```

since '|' is to be swallowed by the parser without interpreting.

As for replacements, should you need ones, check out `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your format string works on any machine. Please note that year is indicated by lower case 'y' and you have it in upper-case. Try the following code:

```
   @Test
   public void testRandomDate() throws Exception {
      final String lastUpdateValue = "13:23 | 26.01.2012";
      final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH:mm | dd.MM.yyyy");
      final Date dateLastUpdate = dateFormat.parse(lastUpdateValue);

      System.out.println(dateLastUpdate);
   }
```

Also, reference [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation for the list of acceptable parse expressions: